# Missing class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory when use the obfuscation method Generate Signed APK

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, signed-apk, release-apk

When I use the obfuscation method Generate Signed APK (`minifyEnabled true shrinkResources true`), an error will be reported. The error message is as follows. But when it is not confused (`minifyEnabled false shrinkResources false`), it is successful.

```
Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in ...\missing_rules.txt.

Missing class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory (referenced from: long org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout.cpuTime(java.lang.Thread) and 1 other context)
Missing class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean (referenced from: void org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug.<init>(org.junit.rules.TestRule))
Missing class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean (referenced from: long org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout.cpuTime(java.lang.Thread))
```

I need to successfully Generate Signed APK using obfuscation. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this option in app level `build.gradle` file**

```
android {
    lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
      abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: It has been added before, it seems that this is not the reason.